# Project explorer Delete Action not working as expected

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Eclipse Default **Delete** action on the project explorer (context menu, key binding) not working as expected.

In Project explorer I do have 2 different files let's assume **".pc"** and **".tc"** files.

I want to restrict the user from deleting the **".tc"** files from project explorer for that I have written custom handlers to restrict it. Actions are configured as below.

```
<handler
    class="MyTCFileDeleteHandler"
    commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete">
 <activeWhen>
    <with
               variable="selection">
            <iterate
                  ifEmpty="false">
               <instanceof
                     value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
               </instanceof>
               <test
                     property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                     value="tc">
               </test>
            </iterate>
         </with>
 </activeWhen>
</handler>
<handler
    class="MyTCFileDeleteHandler"
    commandId="org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.deleteResource">
 <activeWhen>
    <with variable="selection">
            <iterate
                  ifEmpty="false">
               <instanceof
                     value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
               </instanceof>
               <test
                     property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                     value="tc">
               </test>
            </iterate>
     </with>
 </activeWhen>
</handler>
```

But due to this DeleleParticepent wrote are not getting calls for ".pc" file deletion.
Also, this misbehaves for shortcuts, context menus differently.

What I want to achieve, I should restrict the deleting of some files according to extension and some not, and my participant should call if the file is deleting. And this should work for the context menu, shortcut.

Comment: Why not just write a proper `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants` delete participant? Delete participants can reject deletes.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I have thought, but I am just restricting the deleting file from Project Explorer but from other custom views allowing to delete ".tc" file.  For this case delete participant should get a call if the file is deleting from the custom view. And delete participant is common for both ".pc" and ".tc" files. Delete participants deleting there many supporting files which are common for both.